# How to filter some protocols on all ports

Tags: networking, centos, port, filter

Under CentOS, how can I filter traffic by protocol rather than by port?

For example, I would like to filter ftp traffic regardless of the port being used in order to prevent users on the network from using ftp.

I would like to drop the packet, not reject them.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a legitimate, although rudimentary, question.

Comment: Agreed.  It seems entirely on target for serverfault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking about is typically called an "application layer" firewall or "layer 7" firewall because it operates at layer 7 of the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).  A layer 7 filter operates by inspecting all packets passing through the firewall in order to identify the protocol in use.

There is a [layer 7 classifier](http://l7-filter.clearfoundation.com/) available for use with Netfilter, the Linux firewall implementation.  It doesn't appear to be an especially active project, but neither is completely stale -- the last update on the main page appears to be from January of last year.

I don't have any personal experience with this module.